# Indent adds extra const to const methods

Tags: c++, indentation

This is my `makefile`:

```
TRASH = *.o complex *~

complex: test.o complex.o
        g++ -Wall -o $@ $^

test.o: test.cpp complex.hpp
        g++ -Wall -c -o $@ $<

complex.o: complex.cpp complex.hpp
        g++ -Wall -c -o $@ $<

PHONY: clean beauty

clean:
        rm -f $(TRASH)

beauty:
        indent -npsl -brf -cdb test.cpp complex.cpp complex.hpp
```

My indent options format code like this:

```
int function () {

 /*
    Comments
 */
}
```

**Problem:**

If I have some C++ function that has prototype: `Complex method_name(arguments) const;` Whenever I use `make beauty` on `.cpp` file for some reason it adds one more `const`, and my function becomes like this:

```
Complex method_name(arguments) const const {
   /*
    Comments
   */
}
```

**Note:** Header file is indented just fine, but `.cpp` file is indented like I described above.

Does anyone know what could be the cause of this?

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with `make` but with the `indent` program. It looks like a bug in `indent` do me.

Comment: [Here is a bug report on GNU indent about this](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-indent/2014-05/msg00004.html). It doesn't seem to be clearly resolved in the mail list thread, though. :|

Comment: Thanks guys, I was losing my mind whole day over this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I've received confirmation, this is officially bug in current indent version.